# Python lambda expression, use String in list as operant

Tags: python

Lets say I have a simple list as  `lis = [5, *, 2]`

Is it possible to do something along the line of:

```
print(reduce(lambda x,y,z: float(x) y float(z), lis))
10
```

I'd like to use the string given in the list to determine the operand.

Comment: How do you plan to treat `*` in a list as valid syntax?

Comment: Aside: Pythonistas prefer to use the identifier `lst` to refer to a list, rather than `list`, because `list` shadows the python builtin.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you can't place the `*` operator in a list, as it is not a value in Python. Instead you can use the `mul` function from the `operator` package:

```
from operator import mul
```

Then, assuming that you have the following list:

```
lst = [5, mul, 2]
```

you can do the following:

```
a, op, b = lst
print(op(a,b))
```

which should print:

```
10
```

.

Answer (score 2):

Operators can't be passed around in Python -- `reduce(+, [1,2,3])` would give you a `SyntaxError`. Similarly, your operator in the middle of the list would as well.

If you're looking to use strings to look up operators, you can construct a dictionary using the `operator` module.

```
SYMBOL_TO_OPERATOR = {"*": operator.mul,
                      "+": operator.add, ...}
```

Those are just normal methods though -- you can't use them with 'infix' notation as you can the symbols.

Additionally, this doesn't make much sense as a `reduce` operation (nor would that be very idiomatic python). You could easily do something like:

```
statements = [[1, "*", 5], [2, "+", 9]]
results = [SYMBOL_TO_OPERATOR[symbol](a, b) for a, symbol, b in statements]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if I am misunderstanding, but I believe something like below would accomplish what you are asking:

```
import operator

operators = {
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.div
}

dynamic_operator = lambda x,y,z: operators[y](x, z)

some_list = [5, '*', 5]
print dynamic_operator(*some_list)
```

You would need to expand on the `operators` dictionary to encompass all the operations you want to handle dynamically. For more operator functions, see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html

Comment: I'm trying this method out at the moment. What does the '*' mean in (*some_list) ?

Comment: You can use `*` to unpack lists into arguments. E.g. doing `somefunction(*[a, b])` is the same as doing `somefunction(a, b)`, and can be used when arguments are completely dynamic. For more information, see: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists